# Zookeeper and curator settings under unstable network

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a ZK that deployed in a data center and interacted with lots of curator clients. Connection loss events are always detected in the client sides as the network condition is not so stable.

Now I am looking at some good practice for the settings of ZK and Curator under the unstable network environment.

What I think of is to increase the session timeout on both ZK and curator sides, like increase to 1 minute.

Looking forward to your replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a network reliability issue increasing the session timeout will only delay the outcome. Also the overall latency of the system will increase.

There could be multiple possible reasons of connection loss other than network. Please refer the link below.

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/Troubleshooting
http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_commonProblems

Also you can use below to check zk cluster health

https://github.com/phunt/zk-smoketest